# Unrecognized function or variable 'x'. in matlab

Tags: matlab

trying to write Matlab code to implement Euler's Method to solve the differential equation y'=2+2x-x2 subject to initial condition y(0)=1. Please use step size 0.1 and estimate the value at x=1 and x=2.

when i run the code i get Unrecognized function or variable 'x'

```
dy =(2+2*x-2^2);

  x0 = 1;


  xn = 2;


  y = 1;

  h = 0.1;

  fprintf ('x \t\t y (Euler)\t y (analytical)\n') %data table header 

  fprintf ('%f \t %f\t %f\n' ,x0,y,(x0));


  for x = x0 : h : xn-hypot

   y= y + 2+2*x-2^2 * h;


  x = x + h;


  fprintf ('%f \t %f\t %f\n',x,y,(x));

 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the first line of the code:

```
dy =(2+2*x-2^2);
```

as this is the first statement of the code, the variable `x` has not been declared and Matlab returns the error you provided.

I would like also to add two comments:

1. Because in the for loop you already typed in the derivative, `y= y + 2+2*x-2^2 * h;`, you do not need to state the derivative in the beginning of the code. Either comment or delete the first line.
2. However, a better approach to make the Euler Method a little more general, is to use [function handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html). Then you can type in the first line of the code

   `dy = @(x) (2+2*x-2^2);`

and in the for loop use this function:

```
for x = x0 : h : xn-hypot
   y = y + dy(x) * h;
   x = x + h;
end
```

This way, you do not need to change your for loop with the Euler method, and it actually works for any first order differential equation (just change the `dy` function).